# Pink sticky strip inside laptop

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair

I had spilled a drink onto my laptop keyboard. During disassembly, I found this strange item inside. Looks like a piece of sticky rubber.

What is it? What is the purpose of it?

[image]

Comment: Absorbing spilled drinks isn't enough of a function for you?  Some people are never happy.

Comment: It looks like a thermal pad. What's under it?

Comment: Might serve to avoid short-circuits by touching whatever is above, help keep the board in place, ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its most likely an insulator to protect from an electrical short from the keyboard (or whatever was above/below it).

Answer (score 4):

It looks a bit too thick for an insulator, so I would say it's a [thermal pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermally_conductive_pad).

It's designed to make thermal contact (transfer heat) between what's below it (most likely CPU voltage regulators) and what's above it, which is a metallic part (either a dedicated heatsink or just a big part of the laptop casing) that will dissipate heat.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Game consoles have smaller squares of this all over the place. They are always connecting something that generates a lot of heat to some kind of heat spreader. I would not doubt that they could serve both purposes however.